# MFMessageComposeViewController is slower with iOS 10

Tags: swift, ios10

I am using MFMessageComposeViewController to send a sms.The problem is that with iOS 10, MFMessageComposeViewController is really slow. I takes 5-10 seconds for the Messaging screen to show up.

I googled this problem, but I couldn't find too much information.

MFMessageComposeViewController is presented in the old way:

```
if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        let messageComposeViewController = MFMessageComposeViewController()

        messageComposeViewController.messageComposeDelegate = messageComposeDelegate
        messageComposeViewController.recipients = recipients
        messageComposeViewController.body = "body"

        viewController.presentViewController(messageComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            // do something
        })
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Do you have any information about this?

Comment: is this happening on the device or only what you are seeing in the simulator?

Comment: It's happening on the device, too.